# Formatting Excel texttocolumn using Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to convert all columns in an excel file using access VBA. I want to convert the columns from text to general format, using the TextToColumns function.

The code that I'm trying to use is along these lines:

```
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet      
Dim rngS As Range

Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set owb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
Set oWS = owb.Sheets(1)
Set rngS = oWS.Columns

Do While rngS <> ""

For Each rngS In oWS
    rngS.TextToColumns rngS.Cells(1, 1), xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, False, True, False, False, False, False, xlGeneralFormat

Next
    Loop
```

I can use TexttoColumns for a single column but am having difficulty to get it to move across all columns in the spreadsheet. I know that this looks like badly concocted code so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Comment on your code: `do ... Loop` around `for ... Next` is surely not necessary. Regarding your algorithm: Text to columns overwrite cells with the new data, so you just lose next columns when split the first one. To fix it you may copy first column to a new sheet, split there, then copy second column to the right of first one, split, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Access it would seem plausible that this is a contiguous block of data that may have blank cells but not pocketed *islands* of values separated by completely blank rows and/or columns. If this is the case, then the worksheet's [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) can be exploited to govern the cells to be processed.

```
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application, oWB As Workbook, oWS As Worksheet
Dim c As Long

Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets(1)

With oWS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
        With .Columns(c)
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlGeneralFormat)
        End With
    Next c
End With
```

I prefer a *xlFixedWidth* approach while only supplying a single *FieldInfo* set of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers. @Jeeped that solution nailed it.